# Combine two lists and alternating the result in Jinja?

Tags: jinja2

I'm working on a sandboxed CMS so I can't run any pythonic code, other than versions of Jinja.

I am pulling my lists from a database where I split them based on having a field = a certain value.

```
{# rows = command to pull from db #}

{% set row_one = rows|selectattr('resource','equalto','One') %}
{% set row_two = rows|selectattr('resource','equalto','Two') %}
{# Sets my empty array #}
{% set newobj = [] %}
```

From here, console logging either Row one/two will result in showing me only those items that apply to their respective resource type.

My problem comes when I try to stuff those two in an array and then iterate over it to alternate the result.

Here is what I tried:

```
{% for row in rows %}
   {% newObj.update(row_one[loop.index0], row_two[loop.index0] %}
{% endfor %}
```

This seems to be throwing an error on `newObj`

> Unknown tag 'newobj'

I had it stop throwing the error by using :

```
{% for row in rows %}
  {% set objs = newObj.update(marketingRows[loop.index0], salesRows[loop.index0], designRows[loop.index0]) %}
{% endfor %}
```

But this has proved to return nothing when console logging `objs`.

---

## My desired result

```
{# example input #}
row_one = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
row_two = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

{# desired output #}
objs =  ['1', 'a', '2', 'b', '3', 'c', '4', 'd']
```

I'm at a total loss here, any help is appreciated !

Comment: Will `row_one` and `row_two` always be equal length?

Comment: Nope they could change, but if one row runs out, it should just fill with the rest

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience, and since you are not able to run any python code, there is no *easy* way to accomplish this in jinja. Since jinja does not support `zip`, and `max` is not available until [v2.10](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#max), so we need to improvise.

First, you need to get the longest length of either list.

```
{%- set row_one = ['1', '2', '3', '4'] -%}
{%- set row_two = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] -%}
{%- set rows_combined = (row_one, row_two) -%}

{%- set lengths = [] %}
{%- for row in rows_combined -%}{%- if lengths.append(row|length)-%}{%- endif -%}{%- endfor -%}
{%- set max_length = (lengths|sort)[-1] -%}
```

Next, you need to do a nested loop. First iterating through the range of the max length and then `rows_combined` to grab the correct index of `row_one` and `row_two`.

```
{%- set rows = [] -%}    

{# Loops through a range of max_length #}
{%- for r in range(max_length) -%}
    {# Loops through the tuple containing row_one and row_two #}
    {%- for a in rows_combined -%}
        {# checks if a[r] exists if based on current index, if so appends it rows#}
        {%- if a[r] -%}{%- if rows.append(a[r]) -%}{%- endif -%}{%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor -%}

{{ rows }}

>>>['1', 'a', '2', 'b', '3', 'c', '4', 'd']
```

**Tests with 3 lists instead of 2**

```
{%- set row_one = ['1', '2', '3', '4'] -%}
{%- set row_two = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] -%}
{%- set row_three = ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z'] -%}
{%- set rows_combined = (row_one, row_two, row_three) -%}

{%- set lengths = [] %}
{%- for row in rows_combined -%}{%- if lengths.append(row|length)-%}{%- endif -%}{%- endfor -%}
{%- set max_length = (lengths|sort)[-1] -%}
{%- set rows = [] -%}

{%- for r in range(max_length) -%}
    {%- for a in rows_combined -%}
        {%- if a[r] -%}{%- if rows.append(a[r]) -%}{%- endif -%}{%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor -%}
{{ rows }}

>>> ['1', 'a', 'w', '2', 'b', 'x', '3', 'c', 'y', '4', 'd', 'z']
```

Comment: Wow this is incredibly well thought out! Thank you for this. I'm receiving an error invoking range though, so I'm not sure if it will run in our CMS :/, looking for solutions as we speak. Regardless, this will probably be the accepted answer because if someone isn't constrained by the sandbox, it should work perfectly!

Comment: @ether I'm not familiar with CMS, but `range` is native to jinja2, so I wonder why it's give you errors. When I get the chance, I will see if I can find an alternative to `range`

Comment: Our docs say it's supported, but yet it keeps giving me the invoke function error , Appreciate your help on this !