# Merge 2 lists by adding a string in between in Jinja2/ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a 2 list:

```
a = ['user','user2','user','user2']
b = ['value1','value1','value2','value1']
```

Is it possible to merge both and add "_" in between them

Looking for result:

```
result = ['user_value1','user2_value1','user_value2','user2_value1']
```

length of both lists will be same.

tried below no luck:(based on link [Combine two lists and alternating the result in Jinja?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761202/combine-two-lists-and-alternating-the-result-in-jinja)

```
{%- set a = ['user1','user2','user3','user4'] -%}
{%- set b = ['value1','value2','value3','value4'] -%}
{%- set combined = (a,b) -%}

{%- set lengths = [] %}
{%- for row in combined -%}{%- if lengths.append(row|length)-%}{%- endif -%}{%- endfor -%}
{%- set max_length = (lengths|sort)[-1] -%}
{%- set rows = [] -%}    

{%- for r in range(max_length) -%}
        {%- for a in combined -%}
               {%- if a[r] -%}{%- if rows.append(a[r]) -%}{%- endif -%}{%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor -%}

{{ rows }}
```

thank you!

Comment: ok, Converting 2 lists to dict, by in my case there are chances of first list having same set of values" like: a = ['user','user','user1','user1'], what to do in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    some_list: "{{ (some_list | default([])) + [item | join('_')] }}"
  loop: "{{ a | zip(b) | list }}"

- debug: 
    msg: "{{ some_list | to_json }}"
```

Debug output:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: '["user1_value1", "user2_value2", "user3_value3", "user4_value4"]'
```

Comment: ok, Converting 2 lists to dict, by in my case there are chances of first list having same set of values"  like: a = ['user','user','user1','user1'], what to do in that case

Comment: Should output the values as per the lists and result on your latest edit. Try executing the code with input lists.

Comment: Good to know. Would be glad if you can accept the answer in that case. May help others too.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to *loop* the list. The filter *map* does the job as well

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        result: "{{ a|zip(b)|map('join','_')|list }}"
```

---

> Q: "*Converting 2 lists to dict ... first list having same set of values  ['user','user','user1','user1']. What to do in that case?"*

A: Use [*dict*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#zip-and-zip-longest-filters) filter. The equivalent keys will replace each other with the last value standing. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        result: "{{ dict(a|zip(b)) }}"
    - debug:
        var: result
```

give

```yaml
    "result": {
        "user": "value2",
        "user2": "value1"
    }
```